# Pandas Append returns only one Key row. How to resolve?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

The goal here is to combine 2 DataFrames:

The first DataFrame is from a csv file which has only 2 columns: "Ticker" and "Price":

[image]

Next I used `yahoo_fin` to return a DataFrame of the same set of tickers and latest price using:

```
from yahoo_fin import stock_info as si
tickers = ['AAPL','MSFT','TSLA']
price_data = {tickers:si.get_live_price(tickers) for tickers in tickers }
df1 = pd.DataFrame(price_data.items(),columns=['Ticker','Current Price'])
```

and this returns a similar DataFrame:

[image]

Using `combine = pd.merge(df, df1, on='Ticker')`, I believe this will merge the DataFrame and return "Ticker", "Price", "Current Price" for all 3 stock stickers. However the end result only shows one row for "TSLA", and the other 2 ignored.

Any idea what is causing the issue here? Thank you!

Comment: Looks like you have trailing whitespaces for APPL and MSFT

Comment: your first data frame, there is a space before "TSLA" .. you need to check whether the columns Ticker tally first

Comment: By default, `merge` does an "inner" join - or only those tickers will appear that are common to both - https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.merge.html

Comment: @mcsoini thank you for that, didn't notice the trailing 'spaces' on my excel file for AAPL and MSFT. That resolved it, many thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Please check below code snaps:

[without front spaces in Ticker values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XzBBA.png)

[With front spaces in Ticker values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yK1h2.png)

You can observe from above that values of Ticker column should be same to perform a default inner join

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched or copied, or even consumed by users of adaptive technologies like screen readers. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Comment: I will put the code lines instead of screenshots soon